# ReInit Swiper after an AJAX Call Wordpress

Tags: javascript, ajax, wordpress

I'm posting here because after many hours of research and some headache I didn't find a solution to a problem with swiper JS in my website.

In my case, I have a WordPress website and I have an archive page with many listings each one with a slider (Swiper JS) that shows relevant images of the listing.

It works fine until I apply a filter to the page (Eg. select to show property with 4 beds) (so I think before I make an AJAX request).

The page reloads with AJAX and shows only relevant listings, the only problem is that the Swiper Slider doesn't work anymore, in fact, I cannot slide it.

By logic, I think I need to reinitialize Swiper after every AJAX call but as I'm not so good at AJAX I'm kind of wondering if anyone can point me into the right direction. Thank you very much.

My Swiper Code:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
const swiper = new Swiper('.swiper', {
  // Optional parameters
    direction: 'horizontal',
    effect: 'slide',
    speed: 150,
    loop: true,
    observer: true,

  // Navigation arrows
  navigation: {
    nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
    prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
  },
    
      pagination: {
    el: '.swiper-pagination',
  },
});

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use [swiper lazy](https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#lazy-loading) and [param-lazy-loadPrevNext](https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#param-lazy-loadPrevNext) ?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I've added the lazy but when I filter with ajax, swiper won't load the images anymore and the slider button don't work. Same as before but now they remain blank for the lazy load

Answer (score 0):

You're probably right. When the results container with the Swiper instances updates, Swiper needs to re-initialize the new result elements when they are attached to the DOM.

You should be able to re-use the same Swiper initializer. Just place it in a separate function. Then call that function on document load (as you are now) and when the AJAX results load, after the DOM is updated.

Example:

```js
let swiper;

function initSwiper() {
  swiper = new Swiper('.swiper', {
    // Optional parameters
      direction: 'horizontal',
      effect: 'slide',
      speed: 150,
      loop: true,
      observer: true,

    // Navigation arrows
    navigation: {
      nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
      prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
    },
      
        pagination: {
      el: '.swiper-pagination',
    },
  });
}

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  initSwiper(); // <---------------
  
  // ...

  $.ajax({
    url: '/ajax-url/',
    dataType: "json",
    type: "Post",
    async: true,
    data: { },
    success: function (data) {
       $('#results').html(data.results_html);
       initSwiper(); // <---------------
    },
    error: function (xhr, exception) {
        // Error handling
    }
  }); 
});
```

Comment: Hi Dev, thanks a lot for the answer I'm now going to implement what you suggest and reach back

Comment: Hey Dev, the #results stands for what?

Comment: #results is just an example of a possible container element with an id of "results". i.e. <div id="results">...</div>, where the HTMl within that element is replace by new results by your JavaScript when the results change.